# Does there exist one relation is both reflexive, symmetric, transitive, antisymmetric?

Tags: relations

Basically, we have 4 types of relations: reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transtive. And then we separate 4 above types into 2 new definition:

1. One relation is reflexive, symmetric, transitve called equivalent relation.
2. One relation is reflexive, antisymmetrc, transitive called order relation.

All of them above are basic knowledge of elementary set theory.

So the question I wonder is "Does there exist one relation is both reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric and transitive? If yes, so what is it called?"

Honestly, I have been finding out in the internet about my wonder, but of course I cannot see anything. Therefore, I post my question on here to ask everyone my question.
Thanks for your helping.

Comment: What do you mean by anti-symmetric? Wouldn't it require a sign, an ordering?

Comment: Well, antisymmetric means $a\sim b$ and $b \sim a$ implies that $a=b$, and symmetric means that $a\sim b$ implies $b\sim a$, so.....

Comment: If it is both, $a \sim b \Longrightarrow b\sim a \Longrightarrow a=b$ then all equivalence classes (it is also transitive) have one element. And every singleton defines such a relation. So the answer is: yes, there is exactly one such relation, but it is a useless one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\sim$ is symmetric. Then for all elements $a,b$ in the ambient set $S$, we have that $a\sim b$ implies $b\sim a$. But if $\sim$ is antisymmetric, then $a\sim b$ and $b\sim a$ together imply $a=b$. Hence $\sim$ is in fact equality.

Comment: So if one relation is both symmetric and anti-symmetric, it is called "equality" relation?

Comment: Yes, @VAKK_19. What I mean is that, then, $\sim$ behaves precisely like $=$.

Comment: wow I get it. But why does not any textbook I have found in the internet mention "equality" relation? That's so confusing. Or at least, why do not we claim "equality" relation as an official relation? If that we will have 5 types of relation:  reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, transitive and "equality".

Comment: @VAKK_19 Not only those two properties (symmetric and anti-symmetric). But the **four** properties you named in your question implies that $\sim$ is equality..

Comment: "equality" is not a property of the relations. Equality IS a relation.

Comment: So in my exercise, I have proved one relation that satisfies all of 4 properties: reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, transitive. What should I call that relation? Just write it is called "equality" relation?

Comment: Yes, @VAKK_19. Do you understand why?

Comment: yes I understand why. But I am just confused about its name. I'm afraid my teacher will not accept that name because it is not in his textbook and his lecture......

Comment: okay, I will believe in myself. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sometimes it's known as the ["diagonal relation"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Diagonal_Relation#:~:text=The%20diagonal%20relation%20on%20S,%E2%88%88S%3Ax%3Dy%7D), @VAKK_19

Comment: You're welcome, @VAKK_19. Please don't forget to accept this answer if it is satisfactory for you, by clicking the check mark.